# Rails asset precompile aborted on Heroku Push - uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, asset-pipeline

I've seen this error from a couple years ago when Rake would break Rails, but this seems strange.

I deployed my Rails 3.2.16 app to Heroku just yesterday, but now precompiling assets fails with no changes to any assets. Full error below:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/tmp/build_96e5edbe-65ff-42fc-a7e8-e59432cc8de0/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

Curious if there were recent breaking changes or what I'm missing that would all of a sudden change things.

Rake is version 10.1.0. Ruby version 1.9.3 locally and 1.9.2 on Heroku.

Saw this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/heroku/6yjIiP69NqI (from ~2 years ago), which suggested instead of just `include Rake::DSL` to use

```
class Rails::Application 
  include Rake::DSL 
end
```

Still, no idea why that would change overnight.

Comment: Same thing happened just now to me. No real code change that could've caused it.

Comment: By the way, 3 out of 4 of the "answers" below aren't answers. Just add a comment here if you want to comment. And welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem just now.  I updated it the ruby version to 2.0.0 in the Gemfile (it was 1.9.2) and it deployed successfully after that.

To update the version simply add this under the source line in your Gemfile:

```
 ruby "2.0.0"
```

I hope this solves your issues as well.

Comment: Simple enough. I was running 1.9.2 on heroku by default, updated it to 1.9.3 in the Gemfile, and "just worked".

Comment: Changing from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 worked for me too. Something must have changed on the heroku platform if all of us are having this problem all of a sudden...

Comment: Although, I upgraded to 2.0.0 just now, and was unable to push to heroku - looks like some error in their buildpack for ruby...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as the rest of you, just out of the blue went to update the application and push to heroku resulting in this error. If I find anything as I play around will update here.

Answer (score 0):

Huzzah, I was successful running 'git push heroku master' after reinstalling rake and updating the Rakefile for DSL support.

Reinstall Rake:

```
gem uninstall rake
```

*I selected to uninstall all versions

```
gem install rake
```

Update Bundler:

```
bundle update
```

Update Rakefile, adding the require:

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
```

And Update Rakefile, adding the module:

```
module ::ApplicationName  
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end
```

*Make sure to update ApplicationName to your app name.

Committed to git and ran an update:

```
git push heroku master
```

Hope that helps get you guys back up and running, not sure what happened with Heroku but if this corrects your issue @muzcat007 maybe you could update your Heroku ticket to have them look into this odd new DSL requirement.

Cheers

Comment: Didn't try this - got it to work by specifying ruby version in the Gemfile. It was previously 1.9.2 on Heroku (by default), updated it to 1.9.3 (which was running locally already) and it was fine.